# Filtering and updating manually selected features in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo

I'm new to MapInfo having spent most of my time with ArcGIS and am slowly getting used to how to do various common tasks.

Is there a way to filter/show only those features you have *manually* selected from the map window in the browser window and then make group edits to only those selected records (akin to the "show only selected features" and "field calculator" functions in the attribute table in ArcGIS)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MapInfo is fundamentally different than ArcGIS in the way it handles things like this.  There isn't a button to only filter out selected features.  Instead, what you need to do is create a temporary table on your selection.

In the below image, I have a table with 3 lines with one selected:

[image]

And you can see the selection in the browser:

[image]

Now, in the Window Menu, select New Browser Window... Or press <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Choose Selection.

[image]

This will open a new browser of just the selection.  Notice that the name of this new table is called "Query 1".

[image]

You can manipulate data in Query 1 and it will be reflected in your main table because they're linked.  Note, this query is stored in memory.  If you want to maintain this query in another session, you'll need to save your workspace.  You can close Query 1 like any other table.

Also note, that if you deselect the features, Query 1 is still there and you can still manipulate the data as you like and the changes will reflect in your original table.

Comment: Two comments to @Fetzer's great response. Once you have selected some records, you can use Update Column to update a column for on all these features. A query made by selecting features in the map, can't be stored in a workspace as it hasn't been built using a SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

This great [video tutorial: The Update Column Command](http://www.pbinsight.com/support/education/video-tutorials/detail/the-update-column-command/) from Pitney Bowes can answer your question on how to update all records in a column, select records from a column and update only selected records.